# Stored procedure/query executing forever (it does not complete or timeout)

Tags: database, t-sql

I am using SQL server 2005, SQL server studio client. I am having a long stored procedure (it does a bunch of table joins, some delete, some insert and some updates) periodically running (approximately every other 2 minutes).

After I have this sp, I noticed that my database is sometimes not responding (it happens a few times when the SP is not running, and many times during the SP is running). When the DB is not responding, i can't open new connection from the SQL server studio client, if i run a query/sp the status will become running and stays that forever, until i manually reset the SQL service from control panel admin-tools.

Have you seen similar problems?

Is it perhaps because the SP I newly created is doing too much things and cause the DB to crash?

Comment: So it is a Windows Service Application? I think there is a problem somewhere on your SP's that you need to optimize...

Comment: It's a long SP so i probably shouldn't post it here. But what should i be looking after to improve?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your SP might be causing locks. You could use SQL Profiler to try and dig deeper into what might be happening. Here's a link providing further info -

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-track-down-deadlocks-using-sql-server-2005-profiler/

Comment: i havn't explicitly use any locks. Will I still encounter lock issue?

Comment: The DBMS uses locks unless you explicitly tell it not to, and even then it may still use locks in order to maintain data consistency.

Answer (score 0):

A few more quick tips:

- You can use the sp_who2 command to view current sessions on the DB and determine if the SP is blocked, or blocking other processes.
- Check the estimated execution plan for the SP, and look for sources of slowness, like table scans.
- Your SP might be making too many changes in a single transaction and filling up the transaction log or causing it to grow.  Inspect your DB's recovery mode, and whether backups are occurring regularly so that transaction log space can be reused.  Consider batching large modifications into smaller chunks.

Comment: when the DB is slowing done, it doesn't respone to any query, i doubt sp_who2 will return me any thing but i will try it. thanks.

Comment: if the SP is locking tables, then any query against those tables will not return results until the SP's transaction is committed.  It would be very strange if sp_who2 doesn't work at the same time.

Comment: But there is no explicit locks on any tables. Will DBMS do any auto-lock to ensure data integrity?

Comment: Yes, locks are used in order to guarantee the ACID properties that a RDBMS provides you.